# How to check if a field exists in an Access Table using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to check if a field exists in an Access Table. I am getting "Found" message even if the field does not exist.

```
Sub test()
    With Acon
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + myFileNameDir
        .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "synpass"
        .Open
    End With

    With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .ActiveConnection = Acon
        .Source = "Select Distinct [Term - Phases] from Sheet1"
        .Open
    End With

    On Error Resume Next

    If rs.Fields("Start_Date") Then
        MsgBox "Found"

    Else: MsgBox "not fund"

    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    rs.Close Acon.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: If you remove the `On Error Resume Next`, what happens?

Comment: I am getting below error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer** I'm not used to working with fields from Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB and the following code is untested*

Instead of using:

```
On Error Resume Next

If rs.Fields("Start_Date") Then
    MsgBox "Found"

Else: MsgBox "not fund"

End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Try instead to assign the field to a variable, and then test:

```
Dim testField as Variant
On Error Resume Next
Set testField = rs.Fields("Start_Date")
On Error GoTo 0

If testField is Nothing Then 'Or is Empty
    MsgBox "Found"

Else: MsgBox "not fund"

End If
```

When `On Error Resume Next` is used around `If` Statements, and the condition causes the error, then the code assumes the condition is met and falls through.